# Reset PK auto increment column

Tags: sql-server-2008, primary-key, sql-server-express, auto-increment, reset

I've been importing thousands of records multiple times in an effort to get the import running perfectly.

As a result, now when I do the live import before release, the ID columns for the auto increment column are on around 300,000.

Is there any easy way to 'reset' this once I have deleted all the data from these tables?  I only want to for SEO reasons, the URL:

```
Forum/1/Post
Forum/35/Post
Forum/5600/Post
```

Looks a lot nicer and more concise (therefore more clickable in results) than

```
Forum/300124/Post
Forum/370321/Post
Forum/450111/Post
```

I'd rather not delete the column and reinsert the column as it would ruin all relationships and mean I'd have to refresh all my data context diagrams etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need the `DBCC CHECKIDENT` command with the reseed option, not sure I buy that it will improve SEO though.

`DBCC CHECKIDENT ("dbo.Table", RESEED, 0); --next id will be 1`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx

Comment: Thanks, will this work ok if there are 2 records in the table I don't want reseeded?  Can I reseed from record `n` onwards?

Comment: yeah the 0 is the new value, you can set it to whatever you like.