# How to resequence an oracle table id

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have an Oracle table like this:

```
fruit    id
-------- -----
apple     1
plum      9
pear      55
orange    104
..
```

The id column numbers are wrong.  How can I update the id of each row to be re-sequenced like this:

```
fruit    id
-------- -----
apple     1
plum      2
pear      3
orange    4
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle

Comment: Hi, i dont want to delete the table and recreate it. I just want a normal loop to reset/increment

Comment: Make a procedure fetch data in ascending order and update each value. Or if it is auto increment refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593623/reset-pk-auto-increment-column

Comment: Step 1 - justify the requirement.  If id is your primary key, updating it might be a bad idea.

Comment: @DanBracuk - indeed; if this is just to get rid of gaps for display, for example, then using `rownum` or `row_number()` at that point will be easier, safer and quicker than trying to keep contiguous ID values maintained. A synthetic key should be immune to such concerns.

Comment: Please explain why the IDs are "*wrong*". If that is the primary key, there is absolutely nothing wrong with them.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but the 'id' is not a primary key. It is just a column with random numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update your_table
set id = rownum
```

Comment: order by id first. This will break if there's a unique contraint and somehow further down the rows there's a fruit with id=2.

Comment: @JoeFrambach - Where do you want to insert `order by`?  Please write your full query.

Comment: @JoeFrambach - no it won't it's an atomic operation, at the end of which there will still only be one row with ID 2. It will assign the new IDs in a random(ish) order, but it's not clear if that matters.

Comment: This will not necessarily keep the old order (might or might not be a problem).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to guarantee the old order, the following should do it:

```
merge into the_table 
using
( 
   select rowid as rid, 
          row_number() over (order by id asc) as new_id
   from the_table
) t on (t.rid = the_table.rowid) 
when matched then 
  update set id = new_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
i INTEGER :=1;
BEGIN;
    FOR n IN (SELECT your_primary_id  FROM your_table_name ORDER BY your_primary_id);
    LOOP;
        UPDATE your_table_name 
          SET your_primary_id=i 
          WHERE your_primary_id = n.your_primary_id;
        i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```